# django: What's the up-to-date way to flush the queryset results cache?

Tags: django, caching, django-queryset

In the *current* (2.0) version of Django, what *today* is the best way to force Django to ignore any queryset result caches that it may be harboring and to re-retrieve information from the database?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets ... explicitly talks about the cache, but doesn't actually say how to force it to be emptied.

I'd prefer to do this the "official" way.  *Surely* there must be one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I missed something, but ignoring the cache means to fetch the data again. According to the doc page you linked

> In a newly created QuerySet, the cache is empty.

So, instead of the example

```
queryset = Entry.objects.all()
print([p.headline for p in queryset]) # Evaluate the query set.
print([p.pub_date for p in queryset]) # Re-use the cache from the evaluation.
```

do

```
queryset = Entry.objects.all()
print([p.headline for p in queryset]) # Evaluate the query set.
queryset = Entry.objects.all()
print([p.pub_date for p in queryset]) # Evaluate the query set again.
```

Comment: What I'd like – and fully expect – to able to do is to call some "in-line" method which forces the caches to be emptied.  This is important, say, for a data-driven control (perhaps, a drop-down), that might be displaying the content of a dataset that is frequently changing.  Django's caching behavior can prevent this control from timely updating itself.